# Navigation property name from RelatedEnd in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

How do I get both source and target navigation property names for a given RelatedEnd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I need the target reference given a navigation property called 'prop'

```
// Get all related ends and find the reference for this FK
IEnumerable<IRelatedEnd> relEnds =
   ((IEntityWithRelationships)position).RelationshipManager.GetAllRelatedEnds();

EntityReference er = 
    relEnds.First(re => re.TargetRoleName == prop) as EntityReference;
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the property value itself?

Comment: Casting entity reference returned null for me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an entity instance. 
Because the line below gives the NavigatioProperty List.

```
var list=this.ObjectContext.EntitiesName.EntitySet.ElementType.NavigationProperties
```

And the below line returns the list of dependent properties. It can be more than one property.

```
    list[0].GetDependentProperties()
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4988123/413032